# MVC Core build refrences

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So i am trying to create a modularity in my application based on Razor Libraries.

The approach for anyone developing modules is to use Visual Studio , set debug build output to my application modules directory.
The application then picks up module dll and adds it as part.
The approach works BUT the problem is that when the project is built there are refs folder generated in module output folder. 
This is causing the application to throw

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot find compilation library location
>   for package

Removing the folder makes everything to function as expected.

Here is how my application loads the module libraries

```
  Assembly PLUGIN_ASSEMBLY = null;
                        try
                        {
                            PLUGIN_ASSEMBLY = Assembly.LoadFile(PLUGIN.PluginFileName);
                        }
                        catch (FileLoadException)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }

                        var PART_FACTORY = ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(PLUGIN_ASSEMBLY);

                        var PLUGIN_PART = PART_FACTORY.GetApplicationParts(PLUGIN_ASSEMBLY);
                        foreach (var PART in PLUGIN_PART)
                        {
                            PART_MANAGER.ApplicationParts.Add(PART);
                        }

                        var RELATED_ASSEMBLIES = RelatedAssemblyAttribute.GetRelatedAssemblies(PLUGIN_ASSEMBLY, throwOnError: true);
                        foreach (var RELATED_ASSEMBLY in RELATED_ASSEMBLIES)
                        {
                            PART_FACTORY = ApplicationPartFactory.GetApplicationPartFactory(RELATED_ASSEMBLY);
                            foreach (var part in PART_FACTORY.GetApplicationParts(RELATED_ASSEMBLY))
                            {
                                PART_MANAGER.ApplicationParts.Add(part);
                            }
                        }

                        MVC_BUILDER.AddRazorOptions(o =>
                        {
                            o.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(PLUGIN.BasePath));
                        });
```

And the stack trace

```
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List<string> assemblies)
System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManyIterator<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector)+MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable<ApplicationPart> parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature<TFeature>(TFeature feature)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences()
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore<T>(ref T target, ref bool initialized, ref object syncLock, Func<T> valueFactory)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.get_CompilationReferences()
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.CompilationTagHelperFeature.GetDescriptors()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorTagHelperBinderPhase.ExecuteCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorEngine.Process(RazorCodeDocument document)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProjectEngine.Process(RazorProjectItem projectItem)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.OnCacheMiss(string normalizedPath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory(string relativePath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult(HashSet<IChangeToken> expirationTokens, string relativePath, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss(ViewLocationExpanderContext expanderContext, ViewLocationCacheKey cacheKey)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext actionContext, string pageName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext context, string viewName, bool isMainPage)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync<TFilter, TFilterAsync>()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Am i missing something here ? 
Should i follow different approach for loading the libraries ?
Can i prevent generation of refs folder?

Answer (score 0):

The

> PreserveCompilationContext set to false

in project file seem to fix it.